# QGIS - Graduated Symbols - Only display defined range of values

Tags: qgis, symbology

How do I limit the displayed results of graduated symbology to a certain part of the data in a delimited text layer?  I want the symbology to be graduated by size, but then I only want to show the anomalously high values.  I have an expression (see picture below) that finds only the anomalous high values that I want displayed, but I don't know where to input it.  I want the intervals (classes) set based on the entire data range, and then only the results of my expression to be displayed.  Is this possible?

[image: Graduated Symbols]

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question asked per question

Comment: Thank you Josh, for the edit so that you have one focused question. I voted to reopen. Btw, have you tried "nested symbologies" already? You can set `Rule-based` styling to discriminate anomalously high values, then refine the rule by `Add Ranges` to show (or not to show) your 33 classes.

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito, for the vote and for the suggestion.  I had not tried that, it worked perfectly and answered both of my questions.  Thank you for the help :)